# Route not found in rails engine rspec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm using the [forem](https://github.com/radar/forem) rails engine and I'm unable to write rspec **request** specs because the routes I'm trying to use cannot be found (according to rspec). I want to use a request spec to make a `POST` request to create a reply to a topic.

The following in a request spec does not work:

```
post "/forums/topics/#{topic.to_param}/posts", :post => { 'text' => 'reply' }
```

It fails with

```
No route matches [POST] "/forums/topics/first-topic/posts"
```

Here's how things look: rake routes from `spec/dummy`:

```
Routes for Forem::Engine:
  POST   /topics/:topic_id/posts(.:format)     forem/posts#create
```

logs from creating a post from the website

```
Started POST "/forums/topics/welcome-to-forem/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-19 22:23:47 +0800
Processing by Forem::PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vnzhdaRDTye1wM5eQEIAW8W/urG/18PJ02oPqcX3pK8=", "post"=>{"text"=>"asdf", "reply_to_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Post Reply", "topic_id"=>"welcome-to-forem"}
```

from a pry session inside the request spec - showing the path is recognized by `forem` but not the host app.

```
> forem.recognize_path "/topics/#{topic.to_param}/posts", :method => :post
=> {:action=>"create", :controller=>"forem/posts", :topic_id=>"first-topic"}

> Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/topics/#{topic.to_param}/posts", :method => :post
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/topics/first-topic/posts"
```

**How can I write my request spec to create a reply to a topic?**

Answer (score 0):

I guess using string IDs is not considered to be a good practice. Try using integer IDs instead of strings. But if you still want to use String IDs, I think [this](http://masonoise.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/rails-routes-with-string-ids-and-periods/) link could help you out.